# I need a query multiple columns each date in same table

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

I have this table structure

```
Date       | Success      | No of success tran.| Failed     | No. of failed tran  
29/05/2015 | Total Amount | count success tran.|total amount| count failed tran
```

I want

1. "Date" to have `datetime`.
2. "Success" to have total sum of success amount.
3. "Number of success transactions" to have total success amount count.
4. "Failed" to have total sum of fail amount.
5. "Number of failed transactions" to have total failed amount count.

Comment: you mean a group by Date (like 29/05/2015 00:00:00) with sums on the other columns ? plop in a create table stmt so we can see structure

Comment: I mean Date like 29:05:2015 00:00:00

Comment: so you might have several rows in there for a certain date, like 29/05/2015? if so do a select thedate,sum(a),sum(b) etc group by thedate, using an 'As' to get proper sum column names

Comment: Hello Dear,
I already did this, but was not success for this logic.

Here is my table data link
http://prntscr.com/7ajpk7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table test999
( id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
thedate datetime not null,
status varchar(20) not null,
amount decimal (10,2) not null
)


insert into test999 (thedate,status,amount) values (now(),'success',9283.92);
insert into test999 (thedate,status,amount) values (now(),'failed',283.22);
insert into test999 (thedate,status,amount) values (now(),'success',3283.92);
insert into test999 (thedate,status,amount) values (now(),'failed',26.26);
insert into test999 (thedate,status,amount) values (now(),'success',9083.02);
insert into test999 (thedate,status,amount) values (now(),'failed',20093.12);
insert into test999 (thedate,status,amount) values (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 17 DAY),'failed',26.26);
insert into test999 (thedate,status,amount) values (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 17 DAY),'success',9083.02);
insert into test999 (thedate,status,amount) values (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 17 DAY),'failed',20093.12);

SELECT
    date(thedate),
    SUM( CASE WHEN status='success' then 1 else 0 end
        ) AS success_count,
    SUM( CASE WHEN status='success' then amount else 0 end
        ) AS success_amount,
    SUM( CASE WHEN status='failed' then 1 else 0 end
        ) AS failed_count,
    SUM( CASE WHEN status='failed' then amount else 0 end
        ) AS failed_amount
FROM test999
group by date(thedate)
order by date(thedate)

date | success_count | success_amt | failed_count | failed_amt   
2015-05-11  1   9083.02 2   20119.38
2015-05-28  3   21650.86    3   20402.60
```